# Convert mp4/avi to gif but the gif is very slow

Tags: python, gif, mp4

I use the below to convert my mp4 file to gif file. It worked fine but when I load the gif with browser or local tool, the gif is moving very slow. E.g. It was an animal moving from point A to point B, in the mp4, it moves like normal but when I converted it to gif, it moves 5times(estimate) slower than the mp4.

Code;

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

videoClip = VideoFileClip("my-life.mp4")

videoClip.write_gif("my-life.gif")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

`(<your.gif>,fps=25,program='ffmpeg') or (<your.gif>,fps=25,program='imageio)`

```
` videoClip.write_gif("my-life.gif", <one of the above goes here>")`
```

Comment: thank you and it seems like my mp4 is in 60fps but why when we adjust to 25 it become the same as the original mp4?

Comment: I adjusted it to 10 fps and it runs the same speed now. thank you.

Comment: Not sure why but if you have an answer, please share.

Comment: Your welcome! Sorry i put 25fps, 10 is much slower and better for a gif. I believe it because of the nature gifs. 30fs is like what we see while watch most video playback, dropping the frame rate slows down how long it should take before the code need to render or display the next image.